# c++ private constructors

Tags: c++, singleton, private-constructor

If I don't want to allow anyone to create an instance of my class except for my static functions (I think this is called singleton/factory?), is it enough to make the default constructor private, or do I also need to explicitly define and make private a copy constructor and assignment operator?

Comment: That depends; do you want consumers of the class to be able to make copies of instances returned by your static function?

Comment: no, I want only one instance globaly

Comment: As an additional note to all of these answers, the new c++0x allows you to use " = delete" to delete a function.  So, in a class A, you can create the copy constructor in public as normal, except as "A(const A& a) = delete;".  Same with "A& operator= (const A& rhs) = delete;".

Comment: @GMan, in my opinion, it seems bad form for a coder to simply tell other people working on code not to do something and depending on them to listen (in this case not making extra instances); it is much better to actually enforce something through code.  Head First Design Patterns tackles the question baruch touches on.

Comment: @Chance: W.r.t copying, sure; then again, if copying makes sense then just leave it alone. When was the last time your or someone you know accidentally made a `std::ostream` and used that instead of `std::cout`? Just leave the class alone and make a global instance.

Comment: @GMan: I make std::ostream objects all the time. std::ofstream is a great example. OK.That's a bit pedantic of me. But I agree with Chance. You should not expect the user of an object to understand correct behavior. It is the responsibility of the designer of an object to enforce that it can not be used incorrectly. This means that we only have to do it correctly once and the compiler will then enforce the rules outlined by the designer. If we make it upto the user then somebody else will create another one in another part of the code without realising that one has already been created.

Comment: @Martin: I didn't say "Make a `std::ostream`" I said "Make a `std::ostream` by accident in place of `std::cout`." Again: When have you done this? If you have a class, and you want it to be globally available, then just make a global instance. I don't see what's so hard about that. And if your class breaks when its copied, like *many* do, then make it noncopyable. (Notice that's irrespective of whether or not it's global.) If it can be copied fine, then let it be copied!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would do all 3 of those manager functions. If not, you do not want to be able to access the copy constructor. For example, this is valid:

```
Singleton * s;
Singleton copy( *s );
```

So do something like:

```
class Singleton
{
private:
  Singleton();
  Singleton(const Singleton &);
  Singleton & operator = (const Singleton &);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Making the constuctor private is for the factory method pattern.  The singleton pattern needs a factory method.
boost has noncopyable if you don't want your class to be copied, but as James McNellis already commented: decide whether users should be able to copy the class.  Because raw pointers and the inherent memory management should not have a place in classes anymore, the question of having classes copied is mostly for classes that use resources or possibly large containers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, usually you have to. If not, you could construct a new object by copy:

```
MyClass newObject = your_singleton_of_type_MyClass;
```

In this case the copy constructor is issued, creating two objects actually. Making the copy constructor private prevents the copy by making this code illegal.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one instance, then yes, the copy constructor should be private.  The assignment operator shouldn't matter, because it will be impossible to use anyway.